# Check the existence of a record before inserting a new record

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using the Ado.net Entity Framework for the first time and I need to check if this record exist before I insert it to the database. Preferably I'd search if AuthodSSID exists  and not the key (AuthorID). I'm using VS2010, Framework 4. System.Data.Entity is 3.5.0.0.

I googled, but found no answer for this question.

```
PublishingCompanyEntities publishContext;
publishContext = new PublishingCompanyEntities();

private void createNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Author newAuthor = new Author();
    newAuthor.FirstName = firstName.Text;
    newAuthor.LastName = lastName.Text;
    newAuthor.AuthodSSID = 20;
    newAuthor.AuthorID = 10
//Check if record exist here
    publishContext.AddToAuthor(newAuthor);//insert if does not exist

}
```

Comment: Old but still looks like a DUP; more info can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802286/best-way-to-check-if-object-exists-in-entity-framework

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to check if object exists in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802286/best-way-to-check-if-object-exists-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The only way to check if a record exists is to query the record and see if anything comes back:

```
var existingAuthorCount = publishContext.Author.Count(a => a.AuthodSSID == 20);
if (existingAuthorCount == 0) 
{
    // Do your insert
}
```

Comment: Working, just had to figure out why didn't the .Count appear. Simple, 
using System.Linq; was missing on the top! Tkx!!

Comment: From the wise advice of the infamous Eric Lippert: You have a jar entirely full of pennies. Someone asks you "are there any pennies in that jar?". **Do you count them and then compare the answer to zero, or do you see if there is at least one penny in the jar?** ([Citation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194908/safely-checking-non-repeatable-ienumerables-for-emptiness#comment11574518_9194908)). The performance of this solution will depend on the number of rows contained in `Author`. I've updated my answer to limit the resulting query to only look for 1.

Comment: Can you not use publishContext.Author.Any(a => a.AuthodSSID == 20) or is .Any() unavailable in EF?

Comment: I would reiterate what Trevor said. I'm currently using .Any in what I think is the same situation.

Comment: Yes, please use the answer from @M.Babcock if `Any` is supported by your version of EF.

Answer (score 12):

Something like this should work:

```
if (publishContext.Author.Select(a => a.AuthodSSID).Where(id => id == 20).Take(1) == null)
    // It doesn't exist
else
    // It does exist
```

Based on my (albeit fundamental) understanding this should produce a SQL statement equivalent to:

```
SELECT TOP(1) AutodSSID FROM Author WHERE AuthodSSID = 20;
```

---

Another simpler approach may be to use the `Any` extension method:

```
if (!publishContext.Author.Any(a => a.AuthodSSID == 20))
    // Put your insert logic here.
```

Comment: This would work and is best if you want to update the author if it does exist.  However, this will select all columns for the author, which you may not need.  Doing a count as in my answer would be more efficient.

Comment: @Jacob - A count would effectively be the same as including a select of a single column, but using `SingleOrDefault` I would think it would be doing a `TOP 1` where `COUNT(*)` still needs *all* of the records, or am I missing something?

Comment: Good question.  My concern with `TOP 1` is that all *columns* are still returned for that one row.  `COUNT` could possibly require more table scanning on the database, but only an integer would be returned.  Maybe the best choice is to do a `Where`, then a `Select` of the primary key, followed by a `Take(1)`.  That should resolve both concerns.

Comment: @Jacob - Sort of like my current answer?

Comment: No.  Your current answer returns all columns.

Answer (score 4):

I personally prefer this approach from a .NET point of view. It is cleaner and if you care about speed (in .NET), it is more efficient, however the SQL is not that flash;

```
private bool CheckIfEntityRecordExists(Entity e)
{
    var retVal = false;
    using (var db = new EntityContext())
    {
        retVal = db.AdviserClients.Any(a => a.Id == e.Id);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

So for a efficient SQL statement, the following is the best:

```
private bool CheckIfEntityRecordExists(Entity e)
{
    var retVal = false;
    using (var db = new EntityContext())
    {
        retVal = db.AdviserClients.Count(a => a.Id == e.Id) > 0;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: though i had upvoted your answer but from performance perspective one should use db.context.Any() as db.contex.count() will iterate all the data while .Any will stop at 1st match only.

Comment: Using Any is the least expensive method of using EF to check if a row exist in the DB. This is my standard way to go for all such checks.

Answer (score 2):

### [This method is advised to only be used for migrations to seed data, not as an upsert method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272455/ef-is-it-ok-to-use-dbsett-addorupdate-outside-of-migrations)

There is so called "upsert" operation available in EF v5.0+

```
publishContext.Author.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id, newAuthor)
```

AddOrUpdate can be found in the "System.Data.Entity.Migrations" namespace, so don't forget to add:

```
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
```

The AddOrUpdate operation is not atomic. But *if (existingAuthorCount == 0) {// Do your insert} isn't also.

Comment: Whats up :DDDDDD

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is search (with linq) for an author with that ID.

The `Where()` method will return a collection of authors you only need one, so you use `FirstOrDefault()` which returns the first element or null if there is nothing. You could also use `SinglOrDefault` which throws an exception if there is more than one element in the list, or just returns that element.

Seems @Jacob has an excellent, more efficient approach!

```
var author = publishContext.Authors.Where
                               (a=>a.AuthodSSID == 10).FirstOrDefault();
if(author == null) //none exist
{//don't bother creating one unless you need to..
    Author newAuthor = new Author();
    newAuthor.FirstName = firstName.Text;
    newAuthor.LastName = lastName.Text;
    newAuthor.AuthodSSID = 20;
    newAuthor.AuthorID = 10
    publishContext.AddToAuthor(newAuthor);//insert if does not exist
}
```