# Is LINQ's Any method efficient?

Tags: linq

Does the `Any` method in LINQ iterated over the entire collection or return true when the first successful iteration occurs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Any` method will only iterate over the minimum number of elements necessary.  As soon as it finds a matching element it will return immediately

It's *roughly* implemented as follows

```
public static bool Any<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, bool> predicate) {
  foreach (var cur in enumerable) {
    if (predicate(cur)) { 
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

In the worst case (none or last matching) it will visit all elements.  In the best case (first matching) it will only visit 1

Comment: I was hoping that was the case, thanks. I was originally using `Count() > 0` and realized it was a very expensive operation.  I rediscovered `Any` and have been using it everywhere.:)

Answer (score 2):

The latter - you can look at the code with ReSharper to verify that if you download a trial version.

As to whether Any is efficient - it's not when e.g. a Count property is available as an alternative. But it does arguably express intent well.

Comment: If the IEnumerable<T> is actually a List<T> does Count() use the list's Count property?

Comment: That is true, but I'm working with sequences that haven't been realized yet. Actually, I'm writing a generic library of methods to supplement `Enumerable`.  So I don't know what the given sequence is except that it implements `IEnumerable<T>`.  I could ask of course, which is why I've asked the above.  I am wondering whether I need to special case for `List<T>` and other types that have a `Count` or `Length` property.

Comment: If you're working with sequences that haven't been realized yet, make sure to take care over whether they're repeatable or not. Since `Any` has to read an element of the sequence to do its job, you have to be careful when applying it to non-repeatable sequences or you'll lose the first element. I was having a look at this a while back actually in case it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194908/safely-checking-non-repeatable-ienumerables-for-emptiness

Comment: I hadn't even considered this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Any returns true as soon as it finds a successful match to the predicate, though if none exist, it will have iterated across the entire collection.